# Javascript variable = variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript to make a variable always equal a variable? Like having `var1 = var2` but when `var2` updates, so does `var1`.

Example

```
var var1 = document.getElementById("demo").style.color;
var var2 = "blue";

var1 = var2;

var2 = "red";
//make var1 update to red when the statement above runs.
```

EDIT:

The actual context I'm using the code for is in a `<progress>` element with the `value` attribute, and var2 would be a Number not a String.

Comment: I'm sure that's not the real scenario. Can you give a more specific example for what you need this for?

Comment: It isn't it's pretty complicated though... I'm writing a game. I want to make the `value` attribute of a `<progress>` element equal a variable that is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, you'll usually use an object if you want to preserve references to values.

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = obj1;
// obj1 and obj2 both point at the same object
obj1.b = document.getElementById("demo").style.color;
obj2.b = "blue";

//both obj1.b and obj2.b are "blue" right now
```

Comment: Do you have to define `obj1.b` and `obj2.b`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "define". Since they both point to the same object, defining `obj1.b` will also define `obj2.b`. After that, when I say `obj2.b = ...`, I'm updating both it and `obj1`, since they 'point' to the same object.

Comment: I mean define as in say `var obj1.b = document.getElementById("demo").style.color;` emphasis on the `var` part.

Comment: `var obj1.b =` is invalid, and will result in a syntax error. I'm getting the impression that you just need more experience with general programming concepts, and I'm not sure how much help I'll be here...

Comment: @Titilolo3 No, you don't need that `var` keyword there as you are not creating a variable, just a assigning to a property of an object.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I was just making sure because I'm kinda new to Objects and JavaScript in general. And I would vote up your answer but not enough reputation ;).

Answer (score 1):

Primitives like integers and strings are just copied into new variables. 
Here is how to make two variables "point" to the same variable:

```js
var var1 = { data: document.getElementById("demo").style.color };
var var2 = var1;

var2.data = 'tree';

console.log(var1.data); // tree
```

This is called assigning or passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably will want to look into [JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/). Only modern browsers support it though.